# Command line tool in python in a fixed root directory 

Tags: python, command-line, installation

I would like to install my python application as a command line tool that should work entirelly inside the install directory (for example C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\application)
The problem is I would like to reffer in runtime to the submodules and resources from within the application directory three. If I install the app with  [console_scripts] option the default path is the current directory. Is there a elegant way to keep the current execution path of the application to the site-packages directory?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're after but doing this might work.

```
import os
dir_of_current_module = os.path.dirname(__file__)
```

Once you know the dir, you can chdir() to it or do what you want. Remember: You might not always have permissions to do stuff there.

Comment: Yes this partially works ... Thanks it points to the .egg directory and I only have to append the application name. But it works! Many Thanks!